# Start bash script on boot not rooted Android 7.0 and Android 9.0 device

Tags: 7.0-nougat, auto-start

I currently do it manually each time after my phone is restarted. I connect using adb and running this

```
adb shell sh /sdcard/AFolder/ascript.sh "a-dummy-argument" &
```

Then I just disconnect the cable and script continue working.

How I can achieve the same thing on non rooted Android 7.0 and Android 9.0 devices(I have 2 and I would like to do this on both)? I would like to avoid rooting. From what I was reading it can not be done without rooting. My question is, would it be possible to install TWRP, backup stock ROM, modify stock ROM so that it would have an additional file `ascript.sh` (or run it from sd card) which will be started at startup. Then flash this modified ROM, to avoid doing this manually. Is this possible?

Note: adb via tcp I believe is not an option as to make adb work via tcp on non rooted device after each reboot we need to connect the device to PC first to switch to tcpip, so we back to the task how to avoid after reboot connecting phone to PC.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ryosoftware.initd btw android doesn't have bash it uses MirBSD Korn Shell

Comment: Also there are other apps which can execute scripts on boot. Termux offers a paid add-on: Termux Boot for the same purpose. But apps cannot execute scripts with the privileges `adb` has. So most of the times running shell scripts without root access or at least `adb shell` permissions is not very useful.

Comment: @IrfanLatif with one exception ;) https://www.xda-developers.com/tasker-5-9-2-beta-run-adb-shell-commands-without-tethered-pc

Comment: @alecxs workarounds do exist, many other apps also use. User needs to connect to PC at least once after reboot. Or have to run `adbd` in TCP mode somehow.

Comment: @IrfanLatif I have added a note to the question that adb over tcpip is not an option as this can not be done without connecting device after reboot to PC on non rooted device.

Comment: @user1325696 explicitly root isn't necessarily required in order to always run `adbd` in TCP mode. On non-SAR devices with unlocked bootloader it's possible to set `persist.adb.tcp.port` or `service.adb.tcp.port` permanently by unpacking `boot.img`. // ***"so we back to the task how to avoid after reboot connecting phone to PC"*** Three apps are already mentioned for reference. You can find more similar solutions.

Comment: @IrfanLatif adb shell setprop persist.adb.tcp.port 5555 did not work, trying option with boot.img. Is this is possible on non rooted device unpack and change and pack again? So far I so only guides for rooted

Comment: @user1325696 yes it's definitely possible to modify `boot.img` without rooting main OS.

Answer (score 3):

This app, called LADB — Local ADB Shell, can open an adb wifi shell without ever needing to connect to the PC:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.draco.ladb

Unfortunately you have to cut and paste your commands into it for now, I'm trying to get him to add editable shortcuts. It's a fairly new app.

Comment: unfortunately not compatible with android 7.0